# A question about differentiable functions and step/jump discontinuities

Tags: calculus, limits, continuity

I got this question:

Let $f$ be a differentiable function defined on an interval $I$,
Must it be the case that $f'$ (the derivative of $f$) doesn't have step/ jump discontinuities on the interval $I$ (meaning, there's no $a\in I$ that satisfies the condition $lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x) \neq lim_{x\to a^-}f'(x)$) ?

Thanks.

Comment: $f'$ is allowed to have jump discontinuities, and in fact infinitely many, perhaps even at every point, so long as $f'(x)$ exists for every $x \in I$.  'Differentiable' and 'continuously differentiable' are two very different concepts.

Comment: Can you show me such a function / counter example?

Comment: I'd like to see one too since trivial attempts with constructing it as an integral of a discontinuous at only one point $L^1$ function don't work. it's also nice to keep in mind that there are some 'limits' as to discontinuity of a derivative, it always has Darboux' property for example

Comment: @JohnSaita The standard example is the natural extension to $\mathbb R$  of $x\mapsto x^2\sin\left(\frac 1 x\right)$, but this only works at $0$. This example, however, doesn't satisfy $\lim \limits_{x\to 0^+}(f'(x)) \neq \lim \limits_{x\to 0^-}(f'(x))$ because the limits don't exist, so they can't be different (or equal for that matter).

Comment: I don't like something in this question. I have removed my answer as my head is in weak derivatives. Suppose a function $f : I \rightarrow \mathbb R$ is known to have a derivative $f'$ at each point $t \in I \setminus {a}$. If $\lim_{t \rightarrow a^+} f'(t) \neq \lim_{t \rightarrow a^{-}} f'(t)$ then by definition $f'$ does not exist at $a$, or am I reading this wrong?

Comment: I think for classical derivative, a jump would correspond to the antiderivative looking like the mod function which isn't diffable.

Comment: Maybe if we will be able to show that if $lim_{x\to a^+}f'(x)\neq lim_{x\to a^-}f'(x)$ where $a \in I$ then $f$ is not differentiable at $a$, and therefore we will get that no such a function exists. But how can we show that?

Comment: I think use contraposition as your framework. I would replace $f'$ with the difference quotient. Could using the claim that $\lim_{t \rightarrow a^+} (f(t)-f(a))/(t-a) \neq \lim_{t \rightarrow a^-} (f(t)-f(a))/(t-a)$ help? Since this implies that $\lim_{t \rightarrow a} (f(t)-f(a))/(t-a)$ doesn't exist and therefore $f$ is not differentiable.